# PHP - get first day of a given week number when week starts on day other than Monday

Tags: php, calendar, strtotime, dayofweek, week-number

In my PHP app I have three variables:

**Code:**

```
$year = 2014
$weeknumber = 1
$weekstarts = 6 //Week starts on Saturday. 1=Monday... 6=Saturday and 7=Sunday
```

With these three parameters I would like to figure out what is the first day of the week. In this case, the 1st week of 2014, when the week starts on Saturday, is <del>December 28th.</del> 2014-01-04.

For weeks that start on Monday I can easily figure this out with:

**Code:**

```
$first_day_of_week = strtotime( $year . "W" . "0".$weeknumber)
```

But it does not work for weeks starting in days other than Monday.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking. Are you trying to find out what the previous Saturday for a given date is?

Comment: Are we talking actual week numbers, or just 'whatever the first week was with a date in this year counting from my startday will be week 1'?

Comment: @davethegr8 can you provide an implementation of your idea?

Comment: @Wrikken actual week numbers

Comment: So, the saturday of week 1 is 2014-01-04.. Which takes us to the question: if we change the day on which it starts: should we go _forward_ , _backward_, or some custom rule?

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks for pointing that out.  You are right. According to the ISO standard, the first week of 2014, when the week starts on Saturday, is 2014-01-04. Now I can use DateTime::setISODate as suggested by Glavic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime::setISODate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php), where 3rd parameter is day of the week:

```php
$dt = new DateTime;
echo $dt->setISODate(2014, 1, 0)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 0 = Sunday
echo $dt->setISODate(2014, 1, 1)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 1 = Monday
echo $dt->setISODate(2014, 1, 6)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 6 = Saturday
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/86966)</kbd> <kbd>[**demo #2**](https://eval.in/86968)</kbd>

---

Your example isn't working, because you are using format `yyyyWweek`, which is by default Monday. [Read about ISO-8601 formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and you will see that there is format `yyyy-Wweek-day`, which you can use like:

```php
$format = sprintf("%d-W%02d-%d", $year, $weeknumber, $weekstarts == 7 ? 0 : $weekstarts);
$first_day_of_week = strtotime($format);
echo "$format returned $first_day_of_week\n";
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/86970)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that function. However, I have seen in Google Calendar that the first day of the first week of 2014 of the week starting on Saturday is Saturday, 28th of December 2013 not Saturday, 4th of January.

Comment: @user2070775: first ISO week of 2014 starts 2013-12-30. You are talking about the last week of year 2013, where based on day Saturday it starts 2013-12-28. If you wish to get PREVIOUS week from current/selected one, all you need to do is subtract week number by 1. Like I said, you should first read what ISO-8601 represents, and then see what you need for you application.

Comment: The Google Calendar app for Android 4.3 says that the first week of 2014, when week starts on Saturday, is 2013-12-28. Maybe they are not following the ISO standard